# Skip 1 second in play mp3 the first time

Tags: mp3, raspberry-pi4, sox, gtts

I'm using Rasp4 and I'm trying to let rasp speaks using gtts-cli. It works but the first time I play it skips 1 second.
I run this command:

```
gtts-cli -l en 'Good morning my dear friend' |  mpg321 -q -
```

It works but the first time I run it, it misses the word Good, then if I run it again quickly after finished the first command it includes all the words, and sounds ok. If I wait for a minute and try again I get the same problem.
Then I try to create an mp3 from the gtts-cli command with this:

```
gtts-cli -l en 'Good morning my dear friend' --output test.mp3
```

Then if I play it with mpg321 I have the same problem, so it's not gtts-cli.
I try different players like play from sox but same issue.

**RESOLVED:** check this out:
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/132715/skip-1second-in-play-mp3-the-first-time/132722?noredirect=1#comment225721_132722

Comment: Seems like an OS problem. See [here](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=292234) and [here](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=290324). You may want to warm up your audio device first; maybe play some silence at regular intervals as a keep-alive?

Comment: It may be worth trying your luck at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/